# Sort based on multiple columns in Search API

Tags: search, search-results, sharepoint-search, sorting

We are using search API.

We have a large dataset so we are using the below approach for pagination.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/pagination-for-large-result-sets

According to this document we have to sort on the "DocID" column so which we did.
But we also want to sort our result based on CreatedOn Column.
How can we achieve that?

API:

```
https://sharepointsite/_api/search/query?querytext= 'test ListId:04d24-60-43c-afb3-893523f3'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Title,Subject,CreatedOn'&sortlist='[docid]:ascending'&rowlimit=100
```

After adding Sorting based on createdOn column I am getting the
below error.

API:

```
   https://sharepointsite/_api/search/query?querytext= 'test ListId:04d24-60-43c-afb3-893523f3'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Title,Subject,CreatedOn'&sortlist='CreatedOn:descending,[docid]:ascending'&rowlimit=100
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to add more than one short query, you should use for api in following ways.

```
https://sharepointsite/_api/search/query?querytext= 'test ListId:04d24-60-43c-afb3-893523f3'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Title,Subject,CreatedOn'&sortlist='[docid]:ascending,CreatedOn:dscending'&rowlimit=100
```

For more details refer the below Microsoft Docs.

[Sortlist](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview#sortlist)

[SharePoint Search API - Post Request](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview#post-requests)

Comment: I am adding CreatedOn sorting first and then docId it is giving me an error.    https://sharepointsite/_api/search/query?querytext= 'test ListId:04d24-60-43c-afb3-893523f3'&trimduplicates=false&selectproperties='Title,Subject,CreatedOn'&sortlist='CreatedOn:dscending,[docid]:ascending'&rowlimit=100

Comment: did you try by removing square bracket - docid:ascending

Comment: yes I tried all that. I am getting "Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException" "An unknown error occurred"